# Converting family visa (Abu Dhabi) to work visa (Dubai) without exiting the country

Tags: visas, india, dubai, abu-dhabi

I’m currently staying and working in Dubai.

Is it possible to convert my Abu Dhabi family visa (sponsored by spouse) to Dubai work visa without exiting Dubai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask whether it is possible at all, this is more of a travel topic (*how* to do this would be relevant for Expatriates).

1. It is not possible to "convert" visas at all. You can obtain another visa; your previous visa might remain valid or be canceled. So your option is to get a new visa.
2. Generally it is not possible to obtain a **visa** for a country inside this country, only abroad. You might or might not be able to change your **status** inside the country from "family" to "work"; whether it is possible at all and what is the procedure you should ask in Expatriates.

Comment: Thank you for nuanced reply, that was very helpful. I will repost in expatriates to get the specifics of the “how”.